# F# Piping a parameter into higher-order function or declaring own function

Tags: f#

I have a function which processes an input list into a different type but that in itself is not the interesting thing here.

```
let testList = [(1,"c");(2,"a");(1,"b")]

let rec toRel xs =
    let rec insert (a, b) ys =
        match ys with
        | []                        -> [(a, [b])]
        | (a', b')::ys' when a' = a -> (a', b::b')::ys'
        | y::ys'                    -> y::insert (a, b) ys'   
    match xs with
    | []          -> []
    | (a,b)::rest -> insert (a, b) (toRel rest) 

toRel testList //Expected [(1, ["c";"b"]); (2, ["a"])]
```

This is well and good, and can be refactored into:

```
testList |> List.groupBy xs |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, list.map snd v))
```

Which gives the same result.

When I try and encapsulate this piping process into a function, I run into problems.

```
let toRelHigherOrder xs = List.groupBy xs |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, list.map snd v))

toRelHigherOrder testList
```

`This expression was expected to have type ''a -> 'b' but here has type '(int * string) list`.

What gives?

Comment: normally the answer is to replace `|>` with `>>`

Comment: `List.groupBy` is binary and you're only giving it one argument, so you're piping forward a partially-applied function, not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your pipe is wrong, it should be:

```
testList |> List.groupBy fst |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, List.map snd v))
```

so your function should be:

```
let f x = x |> List.groupBy fst |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, List.map snd v))
```

Comment: And as @JohnPalmer mentioned, it could also be `let f = List.groupBy fst >> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, List.map snd v))`, but that can easily run into the value restriction.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't mention it. Although the value restriction is easy to solve but in this case I would solve it by leaving it with an explicit parameter, as it is.

Comment: "*but in this case I would solve it by leaving it with an explicit parameter, as it is.*" Right, that's what I meant to imply. :-]